# DocumentDB queries with arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, azure-cosmosdb

I have documents with a simple (string-)array property.

```
{
     "id": "one",
     "tags": ["A", "B"]
}

{
     "id": "two",
     "tags": ["A", "C"]
}
```

To check, if a value is part of an array, I could use ARRAY_CONTAINS

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.tags, "B")
```

will return document "one".

How could I query for documents with a list of possible values in the array?

Return all Documents where at least one value of the tags array are IN("B", "C").
-> documents "one" and "two"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the `JOIN` operator , which is used to form cross products with nested array elements, with the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT docs
FROM docs
JOIN tags IN docs.tags
WHERE tags IN ("B", "C")
```

Note that because you are creating a cross product, that you will get a result for each matching child element, rather than for each document.

Alternatively you could combine several `ARRAY_CONTAINS` with `OR` operators, or write a UDF.

Comment: Thank you! That almost solved it. No * for Join queries and () instead of []

Comment: Oops - fixed the query :)

Comment: now distinct function is available and you could do with SELECT DISTINCT docs from ...

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to reach solution with User Defined Functions suggested by Andrew Liu, because - as he mentioned - this `JOIN` approach is returning cross product, so every single match is given as a result.

In my case I needed to determine if a user is authorized to see the document - it is reached by group assignment. Each user has list of his groups and each document has a list of groups allowed to view its content.

For described example, imagine that we have a document which has allowed groups ["g1","g2","g3"] and a user which can view documents in groups ["g1","g3"].

With usage of our SQL `JOIN` method, when we will look for available documents, document described above will be returned twice. Maybe I wouldn't have cared about this if the Distinct function would be available for DocumentDB, but currently it is not (but you can still [vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct) for it).

UDF are defined by using javascript so the code responsible for determining if two lists (arrays) have common element could look like below:

```
function(array1, array2) {
   return array1.some(function (v) {
       return array2.indexOf(v) >= 0;
   });
}
```

To define such script from C# code you can follow this snippet:

```
UserDefinedFunction udf =
            _client.CreateUserDefinedFunctionQuery(_collection.UserDefinedFunctionsLink)
                .Where(x => x.Id == "ArraysHasCommonElem")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (udf == null)
        {
            udf = new UserDefinedFunction
            {
                Body = @"function(array1, array2) {
                            return array1.some(function (v) {
                                return array2.indexOf(v) >= 0;
                            });
                        }",
                Id = "ArraysHasCommonElem"
            };
            await _client.CreateUserDefinedFunctionAsync(collectionUri.SelfLink, udf);
}
```

Finally to run working SQL query remeber about 'udf' prefix required before every User Defined Function call:

```
SELECT * FROM docs 
WHERE udf.ArraysHasCommonElem(your_array1, your_array2)
```

Comment: fyi for anyone tuning in the distinct function is now available in case you don't want logic coupled to a specific collection (udfs live alongside a collection) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/user-defined-functions