# Linq statement instead of SQL with join and array

Tags: sql, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way to formulate the following SQL statement for DocumentDB with **Linq** (for DocumentDB)?

```
SELECT docs
FROM docs
JOIN tags IN docs.tags
WHERE tags IN ("B", "C")
```

This is based on my question and it's answer from [DocumentDB queries with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272321/documentdb-queries-with-arrays).

Comment: Please share your schema too.

Answer (score 1):

In my (very generic) repository I build dynamically some complex expressions for the WHERE predicates.
Thus creating a SQL statement manually wasn't really an option.

So I ended up using a user defined function.

UDF defined at Collection with ID: CONTAINSANY

```
function containsAny (source, target) {
    if (source == null || target == null) return false;
    return target.some(function(item) { return source.indexOf(item) >= 0; } );
}
```

Clientside call:

```
var udfName = "CONTAINSANY";    
var tags = new[] { "B", "C" };
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collLink)
     .Where(item => (bool)UserDefinedFunctionProvider.Invoke(udfName, item.tags, tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class like this

```
public class Doc
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags{ get; set; }
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
private string EndpointUrl = "<your endpoint URI>";
private string AuthorizationKey = "<your key>";
private string database = "<DB Id>";
private string CollectionID= "<Collection Id>";

//prepare document db client
DocumentClient pClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUrl), AuthorizationKey);

//prepare document db database
Database pDatabase = pClient.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == database).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();

//prepare document db collection
DocumentCollection documentCollection= pClient.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(pDatabase.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == CollectionID).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

var tags = new[] { "B", "C" };
var families =  client.CreateDocumentQuery<Doc>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink)
               .SelectMany(doc=>doc.Tags.Where(t=> tags.Contains(t));
```

Right now I'm not really sure that `Contains` method is already supported by the Linq provider (I din't find any doc. about that), but if not, maybe you can finish your where condition this way:

```
.Where(t=>t=="B" || t=="C")
```

I know this is not ideal but it should work. All these things are pretty new, we have to wait a little bit to see more documentation around there and more features that we can use.

Meanwhile, always there is the option of executing directly your query:

```
var items = client.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink,
    "SELECT docs" +
    "FROM docs" +
    "JOIN tags IN docs.tags" +
    "WHERE tags IN (\"B\", \"C\")");
```

You can find more info about how to creates queries in DocumentDb in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

Ever since v 1.4.0 of the .NET SDK the following is now supported -

```
string[] ids = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(collLink).Where(d => ids.Contains(d.Id);
```

Comment: I know, Ryan. But I need to query if an array contains (at least) one element of another array.