# Query CosmosDb - where array contains item(s) from array

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I don't know if there is a word for this, guess there is, but right now I couldn't explain it better than "where array contains item(s) from array".

It might sound weird, but actually it not (I think), and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can do this in Azure CosmosDB.

Here goes. I have a document like this (simplified):

```
{
"id": "2a62fcf4-988f-4ebe-aedc-fb0c664b85d8",
"Title": "Seks års fængsel for overgreb",    
"ZipCodes": [
    {
        "Code": "6500",
        "Name": "Vojens",
        "FoundViaTerm": "Vojens"
    },
    {
        "Code": "6400",
        "Name": "Sønderborg",
        "FoundViaTerm": "Sønderborg"
    },
    {
        "Code": "6700",
        "Name": "Esbjerg",
        "FoundViaTerm": "Esbjerg"
    }
],
"_rid": "k1sVAPf7SQAMAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self": "dbs/k1sVAA==/colls/k1sVAPf7SQA=/docs/k1sVAPf7SQAMAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag": "\"00001000-0000-0000-0000-5a14898e0000\"",
"_attachments": "attachments/",
"_ts": 1511295374
```

}

Ok, now I want to query documents like this and find all, where ZipCodes.Code is in a list of zipcodes, ex. ('6500', '2700').

I'm puzzle here...

I found the [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-reference#bk_array_contains) method and it works, if I only come in with one zipcode - my problem is I come with a list.

Hope somebody can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentDB queries with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272321/documentdb-queries-with-arrays)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per my experience , `expr` in `ARRAY_CONTAINS (arr_expr, expr [, bool_expr])` method is not supported list arguments.

According to your situation , I suggest you use [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-udfs) in Cosmos DB.

I created 3 sample documents as your description.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "zip": [
      {
        "code": "1111"
      },
      {
        "code": "2222"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "zip": [
      {
        "code": "2222"
      },
      {
        "code": "3333"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "zip": [
      {
        "code": "4444"
      },
      {
        "code": "1111"
      },
      {
        "code": "2222"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please refer to the snippet of UDF code as below :

```
function test(zipcode){
    var arrayList = ["1111","2222"]
    var ret = false ;
    for(var i=0 ;i <zipcode.length;i++){
        if(arrayList.indexOf(zipcode[i].code)){
            ret= true;
        }else{
            ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You could select zip array (select c.zip from c) ,then loop the results and invoke the UDF above in your code with the `zip[i]` arguments.

Hope it helps you.

---

Just for summary:

Use the IN operator from [Cosmos DB SQL APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#Advanced) to query entry which is included in the list condition.

Like

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ZipCodes[0].Code IN ("6500", "6700")
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM c JOIN zc IN c.ZipCodes WHERE zc.Code IN ("2720", "2610")
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. I don't really get how this should actually help me, but you made me think more about UDF. Maybe that's part of the solution I need to look more into.

Comment: @MadsLaumann UDF can make custom judgments about cosmos db query datasets available so I think it's very perfect for your needs. Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: No sorry, haven't had time to look into it, as been busy at another project sadly. I will update here when I know more - thanks so far :)

Comment: The answer here will help you with all of your available options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272321/documentdb-queries-with-arrays1

Comment: Well, yes and no. I haven't had time to really implement it in code (C# that is) yet, but I have played around in the Data Explorer, and it seems I can use multiple ARRAY_CONTAINS with OR in between :)

Actually as suggested by @Amitbe link. In that link it's also suggested to use the JOIN, I will look into that too and see if that better.

These UDF - I really don't like it. Yes maybe for something totally unique and custom for my application, but really, what I need here isn't that unique or custom. 
Plus the fact that I REALLY don't like JavaScript.

Comment: @JayGong Ok I actually think I found a solution. It seems to work and it's the most simple as I see it :D
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.ZipCodes[0].Code IN ("6500", "6700")

Oh my god...so much time to figure something out that is sooo  simple... well, it's always like this when you learn a new technology :P

Comment: This one works too, must look into what perform best and is cheapest:
SELECT * FROM c JOIN zc IN c.ZipCodes WHERE zc.Code IN ("2720", "2610")

Comment: @MadsLaumann All right. I thought you wanted to return Boolean type to judge if the entry meets the list condition. That's why I'm thinking of using ARRAY_CONTAINS operator. I have already summarized your solutions in my answer. You could mark the answer for others' reference on the  forum.Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I have just marked it as the answer, thanks for updating it.
However, I have had enough of Cosmos DB now... as I included the above sql i ran into another problem of not being able to use LINQ together with SQL... Cosmos DB is simply too unmature for me and this project.

Now I get this: "DocumentQueryException: Method 'AsSQL' is not supported. Only LINQ Methods are supported."

Comment: I tried using this just now, and it appears to be broken for any lists with a length greater than 1...

Comment: Now distinct function is available and you could simply do SELECT distinct c FROM c JOIN zc IN c.ZipCodes WHERE zc.Code IN ("2720", "2610")

Comment: I do not understand why this answer is selected as the right one, it only works with ARRAY_CONTAINS for me

Comment: @JayGong the UDF link which you provided is not valid any more :(

Comment: @fascynacja It's appreciate to your notification! Already fix it!

Comment: @JayGong could you please assist me with my recent question. thank you

Answer (score 12):

I would like to propose another solution to this problem.
Use `EXISTS` with `ARRAY_CONTAINS` in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT VALUE z FROM z in c.ZipCodes WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(["6500","6700"], z))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:
For each item in ZipCodes, you get a zip and compare with the array of codes you are checking. This, IMHO, is much better than using UDF.

```js
{
  query: '
         SELECT DISTINCT value r
         FROM root r
         JOIN zip IN r.zipCodes
         WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@zipIds, zip, true)
         ',
  parameters: [{name: "@zipIds", value: zipIds}]
}
```

The last param of ARRAY_CONTAINS tells the function to accept partial matches.

Comment: This query will have better performance: `SELECT r FROM r
JOIN (SELECT VALUE zip FROM zip IN r.zipCides WHERE zip IN (@zipIds))`

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that using UDF looks as the easier option, i would not use UDFs in your query's filter, since it compromises the performance of your query. I faced the same problem in my work environment, where things are designed to use UDFs to help in the queries, but the reality is that most of the times we are doing queries by using single values, and using UDF will actually result on the query not using the index. So in that case if you need to validate multiple values in the array, depending on the volume of values you need to validate, you can always write something like ARRAY_CONTAINS(c, 1) or ARRAY_CONTAINS(c, 2) or ....

It doesn't look so elegant solution, but will ensure that it will use the index and will do the best performance in your query.