# API parameters - filter with ARRAY_CONTAINS (cosmos db back end)

Tags: api, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I have an API I am pinging which queries a cosmos db to return records.

I can filter on a simple string in my api call like so:

```
// return objects where '_Subject' field equals "filterTest"
string getUrl = $"...baseApiPath/?$filter=_Subject+eq+'filterTest'";
```

This is working perfectly.

But I cannot figure out the filter syntax to make my API query be based on ARRAY_CONTAINS.

```
// return objects where '_Attachments' field CONTAINS "945afd138aasdf545a2d1";
```

How would I do that? Is there a general reference for API filter syntax somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to query, a query against a property with an array of values looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c._Attachments, "945afd138aasdf545a2d1")
```

Another example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610127/2411713).